# nvidia driver must be installed after I install ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.10, gpu, nvidia-geforce

Hello guys I'm kind of new to ubuntu. 
I bought `Titan-xp geforce gtx`. and mainboard with

```
ASUS ROG ZENITH EXTREME AMD Ryzen Threadripper TR4 DDR4 M.2 U.2 X399 E-ATX HEDT Motherboard with onboard WiGig 802.11AD WiFi, USB 3.1, and AURA Sync RGB Lighting
```

I just installed ubuntu 18.10 on it

but my question is do I have to install nvidia driver for Titan-xp? 
what is this driver for?

and also

nvidia-smi shows

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

if I have to install nvidia driver for Titan-xp how to do it? 
 
and am I on the situation with "no gpu driver installed on my ubuntu?" 
then How i'm watching my GUI screen?

Comment: You need 418 driver form ppa:graphics-drivers

Comment: If you are a newbie, try Ubuntu 18.04. It is more suited for a newcomer, than cutting-edge 18.10 (or 19.04) (this is a general remark, not concerning your immediate problem)

Comment: You don't need a driver to see a GUI. All graphics cards support a generic "fallback mode". You can tell you use it, if you are unable to switch to full hd resultion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [while install nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124465/while-install-nvidia-driver)